# Convert column value stripping html tags into sql view with rows and columns

Tags: plsql, regex

I have a table named data with a column pid & display_data.
Pid is the serial number of all rows.

The value of display_data column is as below :

For each row display_Data has values in the format =>

For PID= 1:

The labels are constant for all rows which would become column headers. Values are changing with respect to labels.
There are total 400 such rows hence, the query needs to be dynamic.

I want to parse this column value,strip html tags and into a new view split it using sql query(Regexp_Replace maybe) such that:
All label values become columns, i.e.

The actual data is much more with many labels and values however this is just sample to get help.

Comment: its pl/sql. my mistake. removed sql server

Comment: Do you need a stored procedure/function or plain SQL?

Comment: a sql statement using regexp/pivot would be very helpful. Just that it needs to be dynamic as in example i have given 2 rows, actual data has around 500 rows with more columns. The only thing constant is column labels across all rows and values would be placed accordingly.

Comment: Yes, there are total 12 labels which would become column headers. I cannot share exact data so gave example of A,B. So we could assume them as A....L .

Comment: Are the labels ever anything other than `A` or `B`? +1 for an interesting tricky question - I'll have a bash - Oracle isn't really my thing, but I could do with practicing my regexes!

Comment: So, the labels are essentially arbitrary strings? What version of Oracle? I **think** that variable names used to be limited to 30, now they're 128 (12C AFAIK)!

Comment: Let me give you an example which is more realistic. There is data table with columns rowid and desc_Data. There are 400 rows in the table. For each row desc_Data hhas values in the format => <span class ="label">Project Name</span><br> <span class ="value">Digital</span> <span class ="label">Dept Name</span><br> <span class ="value">Finance</span>......<span class ="label">Level</span><br> <span class ="value">Level 5</span> ..

Comment: So here the span clas label  Project Name, Dept Name and Level would become column header and is same for each row id. And values  like Digital for Project Name, Finance for dept name etc and so on..would be placed rowwise below respective column headers

Comment: Could you please put this more realistic data into the question and also please also provide the record desired from this data. It's not that I can't figure it out, it's really for anybody else reading the question - all relevant info and explanations should go into the question to save scrolling and to have an [`SSOT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110729/discussion-between-vini-and-verace).

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR Answer

Convert HTML to XML and parse with `XMLTABLE()`

## Long Answer

HTML and XML are both descendants of SGML.

*From the sample data you have posted*, it looks like you just need to remove the `<br>` tags and wrap `desc_data` in a root element (eg `<row>`) for the conversion into XML.

Once in XML format, you can parse the data with `XMLTABLE()` to give you:

- instance of `<span>` ( via `for ordinality`, column name `RN` )
- value of `@label`
- value of `<span>`

This is done within the CTE named `xml_data` in my example.

Assuming `value` always follows `label`, you can convert the instance of `<span>` ( `RN` ) to have the same value for each pair. (this is also done in `xml_data`)

From there, you can `PIVOT` the data into a table that has:

- your row identifier (`RID`)
- value for `label` (`LABEL` is a key word so I used `LABEL_TXT` )
- value for `value` (`VALUE` is a key word so I used `VALUE_TXT` )

This is done within the CTE labeled `key_val` in my example.

For the final query, the final columns names **MUST BE KNOWN** at compile time.  Once you know the columns, you can just do another `PIVOT` for a proper table.

## Notes

As you can see, HTML *is not* a good data format to use for parsing data and/or using the data within a computer (eg a database).

Unless `desc_data` is used for display, I recommend that the data is stored in XML or JSON format.  (I'm assuming you can change the source)

Once data is in a parseable format, PL/SQL is no longer needed.

## Example Code

```sql
with data as (
    select q'[<span class ="label">Project Name</span><br> <span class ="value">Digital</span> <span class ="label">Dept Name</span><br> <span class ="value">Finance</span><span class ="label">Level</span><br> <span class ="value">Level 5</span>]'
        as txt
        ,1 AS RID
    from dual
),xml_data as (
select RID, a.rn - mod(a.rn+1,2) rn,a.label_txt, a.val
from data d, xmltable( '/row/span'
    passing xmltype( '<row>' || replace(d.txt,'<br>','') || '</row>' ) 
    columns
        rn for ordinality,
        label_txt varchar2(20)  path '/span/@class',
        val       varchar2(20)  path '/span'
    ) a
), key_val as (
    select rid, label_txt, value_txt
    from xml_data
        pivot (
            min( val )
            for label_txt in ( 'label' as LABEL_TXT, 'value' as VALUE_TXT)
        )
)
select RID, PNAME, LVL, DNAME
from key_val
    pivot (
        min( VALUE_TXT )
        for LABEL_TXT in ('Project Name' as PNAME, 'Level' as LVL, 'Dept Name' as DNAME )
)
```

Comment: As the real data is bigger, can i use select desc_data from data instead of   select q'[<span class ="label">Project Name</span><br> <span class ="value">Digital</span> <span class ="label">Dept Name</span><br> <span class ="value">Finance</span><span class ="label">Level</span><br> <span class ="value">Level 5</span>]'
        as txt ?

Comment: The CTE `data` is used only to simulate the data in a real table.  so, yes.

Comment: I am getting this error: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 17
LPX-00118: Warning: undefined entity "nbsp"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"

Comment: OP updated with original data